# Is it possible to do authorized calls to Google Drive API using a signed JWT?

Tags: python, google-drive-api, jwt

The following can be read on [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#jwt-auth) :

> With some Google APIs, you can make authorized API calls using a signed JWT directly as a bearer token, rather than an OAuth 2.0 access token. When this is possible, you can avoid having to make a network request to Google's authorization server before making an API call.
>
> If the API you want to call has a service definition published in the Google APIs GitHub repository, you can make authorized API calls using a JWT instead of an access token

My question is : is it possible to do authorized calls to Google **Drive API** using a signed JWT? I searched on the [Google APIs Github repo](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis) but didn't find anything. If yes, can someone give me a link to a page that would show how to do it (preferably in Python).

Answer (score 2):

- You want to use Drive API using the service account.
- You want to achieve this using python.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

In your situation, how about using [google-api-python-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client)?

### Usage:

#### 1. Create service account:

In this case, please create the service account and download a JSON file. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#creatinganaccount)

#### 2. Install "google-api-python-client"

In order to use the following sample script, please install "google-api-python-client".

```
$ pip install google-api-python-client
```

#### 3. Sample script:

Before you run the script, please set the variable of `SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE`.

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = '###'  # Please set the file including JSON values of the credentials of service account.

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly']
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
fileList = service.files().list().execute()
print(fileList)
```

- When this script is run, the file list in the Google Drive of the service account is retrieved using the method of Files: list in Drive API.

### Note:

- The Google Drive of the service account is different from your own Google Drive. If you want to retrieve the file in your Google Drive using the service account, it is required to shared the file with the service account. Please be careful this.

### References:

- [google-api-python-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client)
- [Creating a service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#creatinganaccount)
- [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Very kind from your part even if it does not specifically address the point of my question (the use of a JWT). Does the usage of from_service_account_file function 
implicitly imply a JWT somewhere. Thanks again anyway.

Comment: @Patrick Thank you for replying. Yes. When the service account is used, the private key and client email are used. In this case, the value of JWT is created by the library of google-api-python-client and the access token is retrieved using the created JWT. And then, the access token can be used for using the Google APIs. If this was not useful for your actual situation, I apologize.

Comment: In the docs, they seem to say that JWT can be used *instead of* access token and also that this can be useful to avoid *having to make a network request to Google's authorization server before making an API call*. You seem to say that JWT is used to get an access token. Sorry but I don't understand.

Comment: @Patrick Thank you for replying. I think that your understanding is correct. The flow for retrieving the access token is as follows. 1. Create JWT value using the private key and client email of the service account. 2. Using the JWT, the access token is retrieved. In the case of OAuth2, the user is required to open own browser to retrieve the authorization code for retrieving the access token. But the service account, this is not required. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) If this was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Google Drive API doesn't allow to use of JWT token in the Authorization Bearer header. You may see a list of allowed API's here: https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/tree/master/google. Unfortunately, the drive is not in the list, and an extra step to get access_token for the Drive API is required.